# Merge Dicts in List calculating min, max and average in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, data-analysis

I try to write a World of Warcraft Auctionhouse analyzing tool.
For each auction i have data that looks like this:

```
{
 'timeLeftHash': 4, 
 'bid': 3345887, 
 'timestamp': 1415339912, 
 'auc': 1438188059, 
 'quantity': 1, 
 'id': 309774, 
 'ownerHash': 751, 
 'buy': 3717652, 
 'ownerRealmHash': 1, 
 'item': 35965
}
```

I'd like to combine all dicts that have the same value of "item" so i can get a minBuy, avgBuy, maxBuy, minQuantity, avgQuantity, maxQantity and the sum of combined auctions for the specific item.

How can i archieve that?

I already tried to write it in a Second list of dicts,  but then the min and max is missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make a dictionary where the key is the item ID and the Value is a list of tuples of price and quantity.

If you would like to keep all the information, you could also make a dictionary where the key is the item ID and the value is a list of dictionaries corresponding to that ID and from there extract the info that you want through a generator.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
    {'item': 35964, 'buy': 3717650, ...},
    {'item': 35965, 'buy': 3717652, ...},
...
]
by_item = {}
for d in data:
    by_item.setdefault(d['item'], []).append(d['buy'])
stats = dict((k, {'minBuy': min(v), 'maxBuy': max(v)})
             for k, v in by_item.iteritems())
```